# CMS sign - OpenSSL produced .zip.p7 extractable by zip tool but not the one by Java BouncyCastle

Tags: java, openssl, bouncycastle, sign

I have a .zip file that is CMS signed using BouncyCastle

```java
CMSSignedDataGenerator cmsGenerator = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
ContentSigner contentSigner = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256withRSA").build(signingKey);
cmsGenerator.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(
        new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder()
        .setProvider("BC")
        .build()
    ).build(contentSigner, signingCertificate));
cmsGenerator.addCertificates(certs);

CMSSignedData cms = cmsGenerator.generate(data, true);
signedMessage = cms.getEncoded();
return signedMessage;
```

However, in this way, the zip entries of the generated bytes are not readily extractable by a normal zip tool (an extra conversion step is needed), whereas it could be extractable if OpenSSL is used:

```
openssl cms -sign -inkey key -signer key -nodetach -binary -in data.zip -out out.zip.p7 -outform DER
```

Here the out.zip.p7 could be unzipped by a zip tool, whereas in the BouncyCastle case, zip tool gives "70 extra bytes in the beginning or within zipfile. Bad zipfile offset (local header sig): 70" while unzipping.

What am I missing here when using BouncyCastle? The one produced by OpenSSL is desired, because no PKCS7 conversion to zip is needed before unzipping.

And by the way, I am using Apache's commons-compress to produce the zip file.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve similar output, type of encoding should be specified as "DER".

Refer to Document https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.4/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSSignedData.html#getEncoded(java.lang.String).